# How to merge existing Google Sheet tabs copy a range of variable unknown length and append those values to a new sheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-merge

I'm a novice at programming, let alone Google AppsScript. Hopefully this is detailed enough for you to understand my issue and help me find a solution.

I am currently pulling data from an API and parsing the response into an array, then placing that array into a sheet with defined columns and an undefined amount of rows based on the response. I am using a for loop to iterate through the list of calls and create a new tab in the spreadsheet for each call, which I want to continue to do so that the responses are separated.

What I want to do is after these calls have finished, I want to take each sheet tab and merge them into a full sheet while maintaining the headers, and currently I'm not sure how to find the range to merge because the number of rows per response is unknown prior to the calls being made, and add that range to a new array.

Please help me! Thank you!

I have tried to merge the sheets myself, but so far I end up messing it up and the sheets overwrite each other or the data is incomplete. Again I'm not sure how to find the range to merge because the number of rows per response is unknown prior to the calls being made, and my google searches are coming up with only predefined ranges.

Example Code:

```js
//call the API for each meeting
function callAPI(tokenKey) 
{
  //declare the set of meeting IDs as an array
  var meetingIDSets = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
  var meetingNames = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10", "Name11", ];

  //run through each meeting ID and make an API call to generate the attendance report
  for (var i = 0; i < meetingIDSets.length; i++)
  {
    //get the current sheet to place data into
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //create the new sheet to place data into
    currentSheet = ss.insertSheet();
    //rename sheet name to match the meeting owner
    currentSheet.setName(meetingNames[i]); // + i.toString());

    //call the API to get attendance report for each given meeting ID using the provided access token
    getAttendanceReport(meetingIDSets[i], tokenKey, currentSheet, meetingNames);
  }
}

//call the API to pull the attendance report
function getAttendanceReport(meetingID, token, sheet, hosts) 
{
  //declare participant join and leave time variables
  var joinTime = "";
  var leaveTime = "";

  //declare duration of participant attendance
  var duration = 0;
  //declare the name of the participant
  var name = "";
  //declare the email of the participant
  var email = "";

  //set the API URL to be called
  var URL_STRING = "https://apiwebsite.com/meetings/" + meetingID + "/participants?page_size=300";

  //access the response and parse it into a json file
  const authHead = { 'method' : 'GET', 'headers' : {'Authorization' : 'Bearer' + token}, muteHttpExceptions: true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL_STRING, authHead);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  //declare the participants array
  var participantArray = [];
  //then assign the response data into that array
  for (i = 0; i < data.participants.length; i++)
  {
    participantArray[i] = data.participants[i];
  }

  //title the columns in the sheet
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue("Host");
  sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue("Name");
  sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue("Join Time");
  sheet.getRange(1,4).setValue("Leave Time");
  sheet.getRange(1,5).setValue("Duration");
  sheet.getRange(1,6).setValue("Email");

  //using a for loop, assign each response data point to its respective variable, then assign that value to the intended cell
  for (var i = 0; i < participantArray.length; i++) 
  {
    //assign the hostname based on the given current meetingID
    switch (meetingID)
    {
      case 1:
        hostName = "Name1";
        break;
      case 2:
        hostName = "Name2";
        break;
      default:
        hostName = "unknown";
    }

    //assign the current index variables
    name = participantArray[i].name;
    joinTime = participantArray[i].join_time;
    leaveTime = participantArray[i].leave_time;
    email = participantArray[i].user_email;
    duration = participantArray[i].duration;

    //assign the variables to the correct cells, starting at the second row
    sheet.getRange(2+i,1).setValue(hostName);
    sheet.getRange(2+i,2).setValue(name);
    sheet.getRange(2+i,3).setValue(joinTime);
    sheet.getRange(2+i,4).setValue(leaveTime);
    sheet.getRange(2+i,5).setValue(duration);
    sheet.getRange(2+i,6).setValue(email);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I've added a redacted full version of my code for review - it's not too long hopefully and everything should be commented well, but again I'm a novice so I'm not sure

Comment: That's not a [mcve]

Comment: My apologies. I have minimized the code further. I'm not sure how to showcase the issue I'm facing with less

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer to my question is to use the sheet function `getLastRow` which will return the last row of content for the given sheet, which I can then feed as input for transposing the data into an array for each sheet and then apply that array into a new sheet.